# Every Hamiltonian group contains a subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, quaternions

I read somewhere that every Hamiltonian group (a non abelian group with every subgroup normal) contains a subgroup isomorphic to quaternion group.

But I cannot find its proof anywhere on net or in book. This does not look easy when I tried. In which book/notes can I found a proof of this statement

Comment: The main ingredients is to first reduce it to $p$-groups (which is direct as the property - apart from non-abelian - is inherited by subgroups). And any such $p$-group will contains a minimal one. But a minimal one is in particular minimal non-abelian, and such $p$-groups are easily classified. From there it is just a matter of checking that the quaternion group of order $8$ is the unique minimal non-abelian $p$-group which is Hamiltonian

Comment: All of this can be found in for example Berkovich's book on $p$-groups.

Answer (score 1):

For a reference for proof you can see [Group Theory
By W. R. Scott](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486653773). In [page 253](https://books.google.com/books?id=pOwxAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=William+Raymond+Scott&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBl4Dg3NbLAhUKA3MKHS_QCAoQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Hamiltonian%20group&f=false).

**(Baer)** A group $G$ is Hamiltonian iff $G$ is a direct sum of $A,B,D$ where $A$ is a quaternion group, $B$ is a [elementary abelian $2$-group](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Elementary_abelian_2-group), and $D$ is a [periodic abelian group](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Periodic_abelian_group) with all elements are odd order.

Comment: And you can see this [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25307/groups-with-all-subgroups-normal) question.